# functions.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, html

```
var labels = {{ labels|tojson|safe }};
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var drawLabels = function(id, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.rect(xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
  ctx.lineWidth="3";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.font = "10px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("id: " + id, xMin,yMin);
};


function redraw() {
    ctx.canvas.width = image.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = image.height;
    c.width = image.width;
    c.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
        drawLabels(labels[i].id, labels[i].xMin, labels[i].xMax, labels[i].yMin, labels[i].yMax);
    }
}
```

This is part of my javascript code, i had them both combined in a javascript/html code but a requirement was to separate the `.js` part. It worked perfectly at first but it stopped when i split the content and i get that error on my javascript file called `functions.js` kindly note it's just a part of my javascript code as sharing more than a 150 lines code without being explicitly asked to is probably a bad idea, but the error is apparently in line 1 as the title suggests.

Comment: Whats `{{ labels|tojson|safe }}`?

Comment: labels is a list of dictionaries that has information about my data needed later in the script, tojson and safe just are descriptions, if we may call it so, labels is defined is a separate python code that handles it and supplies it back to the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `labels` is supposed to be an array (look at the for loop in `redraw()`)

```
var labels = [labels, tojson, safe];
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Didn't work, just gave me this error instead `Uncaught ReferenceError: tojson is not defined`

Comment: That's because it's not yet defined. As you said in your comment they're just placeholders at the moment so you need to define them before defining `labels`.

Comment: They worked just fine in the combined code tho, so not sure if that's the solution i'm looking for.

Comment: @lara Could you perhaps post whole file or at least the part where they're being defined?

Comment: @lara That you get another error does not mean that the given answer does not solve the problem you asked in your question. You question is about the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` and not about the `ReferenceError: tojson is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep (move back) line 1 in the original python file
- include your functions.js before the end of the `<body>` tag (to make sure that `var labels=....` will come before functions.js in the generated HTML)

When you factored out functions.js, that file is not being processed by python anymore, so this part `{{ labels|tojson|safe }}` will not get substituted.

That is why you need to move line 1 back into python.